# WinRT C#, Facebook share option inside share charm redirecting to own control?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-runtime, share

How do I add my own share option (target) to the share charm in WinRT? I want to add a custom "share on facebook" button, which would cause a custom menu to pop-up. I successfully implemented this with Settings charm, but there is no ShareCommand like there are SettingsCommand.

Basically, I learned to use Facebook API and now I would like to have a control responsible for sharing to be called from the share charm. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of steps you need to follow to make your application a share target which means that it will show up in the Share charm (you can't add custom buttons there, it's always applications that are listed):

1. Add Share Target as a support declaration to your `package.appxmanifest` file and specify which data formats and/or file types you can accept.
2. In `App.xaml.cs` override `OnShareTargetActivated` which will be called when the user selects your app as the share target. Through `args.ShareOperation` you can access the shared content.

There's a more detailed walkthrough [available in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh871367%28v=win.10%29.aspx), as well as a [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Target-App-e2689782).